# Pausing SuperSized.js through onClick on another element

Tags: supersized

I really don't "get" jQuery - I only use JS for altering DOM attributes client side - but when a tool fits the bill you gotta use it.
I have a SuperSized slideshow running on my page, and I've added a couple of buttons to the navigation bar at the bottom. When these buttons are clicked I open a window showing more information about the current slide, but because it is the 'current' slide, I need to stop the show while the window is open. Everything is working OK, except for this stopping business.
I referred to the api, and there is a call which does just that:

```
$(element).click(function(){
    api.playToggle();
});
```

...but how do I call this in the onClick on another element? I get that the code above adds a click event handler to 'element', I just don't get how I call this function myself from plain old onClick=""...

Any help much appreciated

Danny

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the click event to the element.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

I am going to assume your "button" is a link.

HTML:

```
<div id="btnContainer">
    <a id="slideInfo" href="#">More Info</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function($) {
    $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
        api.playToggle();
    });
});
```

Here is what this is doing. First off, the jQuery needs to run after the page is finished loading. That is done with:

```
$(function($) {
    //Do this when page/DOM is done loading
});
```

We use [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to select the element with the id of slideInfo. We attach the click event handler to the element. Inside the click handler we define what code we want to execute once the element has been clicked. In this case we want to toggle the play of the slideshow. Calling the api.PlayToggle(); function of the supersized plugin will do that.

One thing to remember is that this will pause your slide show so you can display the more information window. I don't know how you are displaying this window, but I suggest using a dialog popup. Once the user closes this dialog popup, you need to then somehow call the api.playToggle() function again to start the slideshow back up. If you need more help on that just reply with more information.

I am not exactly sure what your second question is. I am thinking you want a function that is called when you click the button that fires the api.playToggle() function but you also want to call this function elsewhere in either other javascript/jquery code or attach it to another element. In that case you might consider changing your jquery to this:

```
<script type="text/css">
    function ToggleSlideshow() {
        api.playToggle();
    }

    $(function($) {
        $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
            ToggleSlideshow();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I just simply created a function called ToggleSlideshow() that will fire the api.playToggle() function. Then when I attach my click handler function I tell it to fire the ToggleSlideshow() function. If you want to attach this to the onClick property of a button or something similar all you would have to do is:

```
onClick="javascript:ToggleSlideShow()"
```

I hope I have accurately answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code you suggested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function($) {
    $('#slideInfo').click(function() {
        api.playToggle();
    });
});

</script>


<div id="btnContainer">
    <a id="slideInfo" href="#">More Info</a>
</div>
```

To pause the slideshow using a modal box. It works perfect!

However, when I close the modal box, I am not able to re-start the slideshow.

Am I missing some extra code? (You wrote previous user to ask you if this was the case).

Thanks a lot!t